# connecting react frontend with node js rest api

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, authentication, mern

I'm connecting my react frontend with a rest API from my node js backend folder but once the post request is send i keep getting this
[errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nswHp.png)

```
const handleSubmitData = async (event) => {
    try {
        const { user } = props;
        const updatedData = (data) => {
            props.updatedUserData(data);
        };
        await axios.post(`${BASE_API_URL}/api/auth/register`, { ...user, ...updatedData });
            Swal.fire('Awesome!', "You're successfully registered!", 'success').then(
                (result) => {
                    if (result.isConfirmed || result.isDismissed) {
                        props.resetUser();
                        navigate('/user/login');
                    }
                }
            );
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error)
            if (error.response) {
                Swal.fire({
                    icon: 'error',
                    title: 'Oops...',
                    text: error.response.data
                });
                console.log('error', error.response.data);
            }
        }
    };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As i can see in your Error Screenshot you have defined email and policy field required in your mongoose Schema. Something like this...

```
email: {
   type: String,
   required: true
}
```

Your server is not getting these two required fields, make sure you are sending those in axios Post Request Properly !

Comment: but its taking the passowrd field and sending to db why is not taking email field